# How do I copy a specific folder into the root folder using UNIX?

Tags: macos, unix, web, hugo

I am trying to copy the contents of a folder called exampleSite into my current folder.

My command is like this:

```
cp themes/goa/exampleSite/* . -r
```

however i'm getting the following error

```
cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `man cp`: `cp [OPTION]... SOURCE DEST`

Comment: Still a little confused, could you elaborate?

Comment: `cp [OPTION]... SOURCE DEST` not `cp SOURCE DEST [OPTION]...`

Comment: Don't be discouraged by the votes ncoder. Please understand that, despite seeing and including the complete syntax of cp command in your question you could not figure out the issue in your command, I answered below.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use copy command in unix is -

```
cp -r themes/goa/exampleSite/* .
```

where, cp is the `<command>`

`themes/goa/exampleSite/*` is <1st arugment> i.e. SOURCE

`.` is <2nd argument> i.e. DESTINATION

*Whenever a command you run, fails unexpectedly immediately due to some syntax error. Please run*

```
man <command>
```

This will show you the right syntax!

Hope it helps..